# how to run multiple test cases in appium with testNG+Java?

Tags: testing, automation, testng, android-testing, appium

i am selenium test automation developer and recently started to develop test cases for mobile automation using appium. i want to run 2 test cases consecutively from my testng.xml but it is running first test case properly but for 2nd one it is unable to start with appium error

"debug: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress)","origValue":"Requested a new session but one was in progress"},"sessionId":"44863100-a0f5-43b9-8c34-cda5636916a5"}"

i think for the 2nd test case new session is not created. so it is possible to kill existing session and start new session in java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for me to provide you an answer if you provide the xml.

However what I will advise you to do is that at the end of your tests use "driver.quit();"     so that you don't encounter such an error.

Comment: already used driver.quit() but still getting the same error. is there any way that we can stop the previous session and start new session through java?

Comment: so let me give you an example you create new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities ); then when you driver.quit(); you have to open a new connection.

Comment: have you used driver.quit() within any annotation(@AfterClass or @AfterTest)?

Answer (score 0):

Use session override flag while triggering the appium server, something like:

```
cd appium; node . --safari --platform-version "platformVersion" -U "deviceID" --session-override
```

However the reason for existing server might be that your previous server hasn't been closed

If you are using Mac + java, you can use the following code to close appium server:

```
    public void stopServer() {
    String[] command = { "/usr/bin/killall", "-KILL", "node" };
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("Appium server stopped.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```